# Reorganize and Rebuild Indexes automatically

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using MS SQL 2008 R2, I would like to know if there is any features in the database that allows the **rebuilding of all Indexes in all the Tables** for a specify database at a **specific interval** for example one rebuilding every week.

Please let me know thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Maintenance plans.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187658.aspx)

But you're better off not using these and using something that rebuilds according to need (fragmentation levels) more intelligently such as [Ola Hallengren's SQL Server Index and Statistics Maintenance script](http://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html)